# Azure logic app - modify text before transform xml

Tags: xml-parsing, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app which successfully calls a SOAP api and gets an XML string.

The XML encoding is flawed and in original form cannot be decoded by the built in Transform XML.

If I replace ‘xmlns=‘ with ‘xmlns:foo=‘ then the decoder works. My problem is implementing the replace function.

I tried dynamic content in the logic app input and it successfully replaced the required text but also made undesired changes:
• added an ‘x’ at beginning 
• \r and \n all over the place

How can replace the text cleanly?

Comment: could you please paste the code you tried ?

Comment: This sounds like something that the owner of the service needs to fix.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. 
In the end I found an alternative way to get the data I needed. 
The service is abandonware with a subscription.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

@daniel - As @johns-305 suggested, first thing to take care of should probably be fixing that encoding issue so that your [Transform XML can work properly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-transform).

Here's great blog post by Logic Apps engineer on how to solve this type of issues: 
[Support non-UTF payloads in Logic App with a conversion Azure Function](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/david_burgs_blog/2018/02/27/support-non-utf-payloads-in-logic-app-with-a-conversion-azure-function/)